# Problems with ProcessBuilder (java)

Tags: java, linux, ioexception, processbuilder

So I'm writing a program on linux mint in which I copy gcc from my jar into a temporary folder
/tmp/some_number/. I can start gcc with the terminal like this /tmp/some_number/gcc.
The problem is I can't do the same with ProcessBuilder.

I write:

```
try {  
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("tmp/some_number/gcc")  
    pb.directory(new File("tmp/some_number/"));  
    Process p = pb.start() <--- here comes the error  
    int retval = p.waitFor();  
    p.destroy();  
} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

It always throws the error :

```
java.io.Exception: Cannot run program "/tmp/some_number/gcc" (in directory "/tmp/some_number"): error=13, Keine Berechtigung (means no permission)  
many @s
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=13, Keine Berechtigung
more @s
```

On the other hand i can create a new file in /tmp/some_number/ and write text in the file.

So why can't ProcessBuilder not start my file ?

repository : https://github.com/Xeroth95/MyEditor (its the file MyLinker)

Comment: Is gcc executable for the user you are running as?

Comment: Read the error, you don't have execute permission. Try `new File("tmp/some_number/gcc").setExecutable(true)`.

Answer (score 0):

seems the path inside the code is relative as it does not has a leading '/'

```
tmp/some_number/gcc
```

You are writing the file to /tmp but trying to read it from

```
<present working directory>/tmp
```